# Spring is ignoring commons-logging.jar

Tags: web-services, spring, cxf

I am trying to publish my webservice using CXF 2.6.0. While starting tomcat server I am getting following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException : Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
```

No need to say that I already have common-logging-1.1.1.jar in my classpath. What else am I missing?

Comment: Which version of Tomcat are you using? How did you add common-logging.jar into your classpath?

Comment: @KHY I am using Tomcat v6 and added common-logging.jar in /WEB-INF/lib folder of my web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls check if the LogFactory is loaded multiple times during publish. This might occur if there are jar conflicts loading the same class.